# Stop resetting question counter after a new part

Tags: counters, exercises

I use the exercise package for typesetting exercises and questions. After a new part the (sub)question counter is reseted. I would to avoid this but I don't know how.

MVE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
\ExePart{Second part}
\Question ABCD
\Question EFGH
\ExePart{Second part}
\Question IJK
\end{Exercise}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `\Question` command eventually executes `\@@@Question`, which starts up a `\list`, with parameters `\usecounter{Question}` and this resets the counter to 0. Also `\@InitExePart` does the resetting; we need to cope with both.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@InitExePart}{\setcounter{Question}{0}}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@@@Question}{\usecounter}{\nonresettingusecounter}{}{}
\def\nonresettingusecounter#1{%
  \@nmbrlisttrue
  \def\@listctr{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}
\ExePart{First part}
\Question ABCD
\Question EFGH
\ExePart{Second part}
\Question IJK
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]